# Orthogonal sets and embedding between Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $V=(V,(\cdot , \cdot)_V)$ and $H=(H,(\cdot , \cdot)_H)$  be Hilbert spaces, such that $V \subset H$, $V$ is dense in $H$ and $V$ and the embedding $V \hookrightarrow H$ is compact.

**Question.** If $A:=\{w_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a complete orthogonal set in $V$, then $A$ is also a complete orthogonal set in $H$?

I think that $A$ is complete in $H$. Because, $A$ is complete in $V$, so the closure
of the the set spanned by $A$ is equal to $V$, simbolically $\overline{[A]}=V$. But, $V$ is dense in $H$, that is, $\overline{V}=H$. Hence, $\overline{[A]}=\overline{\overline{[A]}}=\overline{V}=H$, which implies $A$ is complete in $H$. See more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049009/complete-vector-sets-in-a-hilbert-space-and-orthogonality).

In order to prove that $A$ is a orthogonal set in $H$ I don't see how to prove that: $(w_m, w_n)_{V}=0$ implies $(w_m, w_n)_{H}=0$, for every $m,n \in \mathbb{N}, m\neq n.$ Here can I to use the compactness of the embedding? Or it's not possible to prove that?

References are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general you can't conclude that two functions orthogonal in $V$ are so in $H$ (or vice versa for that matter). For instance consider $H=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $V=H^1(\mathbb{R})$ the Sobolev space of order one, i.e.
$$
V=\{ f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}): \hat{f}(\xi)(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\},
$$
with inner product given by
$$
(f,g)_V:= \int_\mathbb{R} \hat f(\xi)\hat{g}(\xi)(1+|\xi|^2)\, d\xi.
$$
Now it's a matter of constructing two functions $f,g$ such that $h=\hat{f}\hat{g}$ satisfies
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} h(\xi)\, d\xi \neq 0, \qquad \int_\mathbb{R} h(\xi)(1+|\xi|^2)\, d\xi =0.
$$
You can always do this, for instance, by taking
$$
h(\xi)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \xi\in [1,2],\\
-1, & \xi\in [3,b],\\
0, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
for an appropriately chosen constant $b$.

Comment: Right, in general is not true. But, when $A$ is a complete orthogonal set? Moreover, by density, for every $v \in H$ there exists $(v_\nu)_{\nu \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $v_{\nu} \to v$, where for each $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$ we can write $\displaystyle v_{\nu}=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (v_{\nu}, w_n)_V w_n$. So I can't go from $V$ orthogonality to $H$?

Comment: @Guilherme: No. By the Gram-Schmidt process you can extend these two functions in $V$ to a complete basis (after normalizing them). The density, as you note, will hold in $H$ but not the orthogonality.

Comment: I agree. The orthogonality is more complicated.  Thanks!